# Вложенные элементы

Tags: python, xml, дерево, атрибуты

Здравствуйте. У меня возникла небольшая проблема. Как пройтись по вложенным элементам?

```
<content id="1" includeTime="2013-01-12T16:40:26"> 
<decision date="2000-01-01" number="96-ÐÈ" org="Организация1"/> 
<element>Hello1</element>
</content>

<content id="2" includeTime="2013-01-12T16:40:26"> 
<decision date="2001-01-01" number="96-ÐÈ" org="Организация2"/> 
<element>Hello2</element>    
</content>

<content id="3" includeTime="2013-01-12T16:40:26"> 
<decision date="2002-02-02" org="Организация3"/> 
<element>Hello3</element>
</content>
```

Мне нужно полчить что то вроде:

> 1 Организация1 Hello1
> 2 Организация2 Hello2
> 3 Организация3 Hello3

У меня получается по отдельности получить значения атрибутов или значения элементов, а как сделать, чтобы получить атрибут и затем элемент вообще не пойму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml.html import fromstring

xml_string = u"""
    <content id="1" includeTime="2013-01-12T16:40:26">
    <decision date="2000-01-01" number="96-ÐÈ" org="Организация1"/>
    <element>Hello1</element>
    </content>

    <content id="2" includeTime="2013-01-12T16:40:26">
    <decision date="2001-01-01" number="96-ÐÈ" org="Организация2"/>
    <element>Hello2</element>
    </content>

    <content id="3" includeTime="2013-01-12T16:40:26">
    <decision date="2002-02-02" org="Организация3"/>
    <element>Hello3</element>
    </content>
"""

tree = fromstring(xml_string)

items = tree.xpath('//content')

for item in items:
    org = item.xpath('decision')[0].get('org')
    element = item.xpath('element')[0].text
    print org, element
```

Comment: спасибо, а я пытался через стандартные библиотеки)